# background image won't load in responsive.css

Tags: html, css, responsive

So i have this problem with an image, which won't load in my responsive.css code. I'm trying to change a background image according to various resolutions of the website. below i post the parts of my codes in html and responsive.css. I already checked the path to the image and the image is in the file which contains html, css, responsive. Any tips how to make it work? I'm a beginner when it comes to html and css.

HTML:

```css
#background {
  width: 100vw;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

responsive.css: figure {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  #background {
    height: 50vh;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 993px) and (max-width: 1170px) {
  #background {
    height: 70%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('../zadanie-domowe-rwd-materialy/obrazy/man-2.jpg');
  }
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="zadanie-domowe-rwd-materialy/obrazy/man-1.jpg" alt="Zdjęcie nr 1" id="background">
</figure>
```

Comment: Try `background-size: cover;`

Comment: You are adding `background image` to `img` tag. But Image in `img` tag will render first then behind that `background-image` will render

Comment: Give the height of background in px

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML needs an amendment:

```
<body>
    <figure id="background"></figure>
</body>
```

Remove the img tag and apply an id of background to the figure tag.

Img tags are not background images, so all images will appear on top of backgrounds. To create the condition, both images need to be added within css as background-image

You will need to add this to your css too:

```
#background {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px; // Or a different height
    width: 100%; // Change to 100% of element or window
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    // Add the follow
    background-image: url('../zadanie-domowe-rwd-materialy/obrazy/man-1.jpg');
 }
```

**Update:** Entire Code

HTML

```
  <body>
        <figure id="background"></figure>
  </body>
```

CSS

```
#background {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px; // Or a different height
  width: 100%; // Change to 100% of element or window
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/350x150');
}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1170px) {
    #background {
        background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/200/300');
    }
}
```

See [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcdm38v5/)

I hope this helps

Comment: so i tried to do as you wrote. i added an in of background to the figure tab and then added background-image to my css, but it still doesn't work - in fact now the website doesn't load any image - the background is just white without any picture

Comment: Make sure you have added a height to the #background. As it is not an image, it will not automatically scale to the background image's height. The example shows height: 500px :)

Comment: i added all the things you mentioned, but the background image still doesn't want to change from the image man-1 to the image man-2 when i change the resolution of the website from 992px to 993px

Comment: Updated my answer with Jsfiddle. Make sure to resize the screen to see results

Answer (score 0):

For responsive only change .css file not HTML . if you want to change the img in mobile or other device ing use in css Like this
`Try it` i thing it's helpful . https://jsfiddle.net/dup1d62k/4/